# Dart HttpRequest json authorization error: server responded 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: servicestack, dart

I have a `servicestack` and use Restfull with `Authenticate`.

When I use `Dart` to authenticate with this code:

```
var request = new html.HttpRequest();
request.open('POST', "http://x.x.x.x:9998/auth/basic", async:false);
request.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=");
request.send(null);
print(request.response); //OK -> Print {"SessionId":"1","UserName":"admin","ResponseStatus":{}}
```

... which happens before I call this service:

```
request.open('GET', "http://x.x.x.x:9998/hello/everybody?format=json", async:false);
request.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=");
request.send(null);
print(request.response);
```

... gives me error output display at request.send(null);

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
>   http://x.x.x.x:9998/hello/everybody?format=json

... give me good output display at print(request.response);

> {"Result":"Hello, everybody"}

Is there any problem with my Dart code? Is it normal.

Comment: I found first error when call request.send(null); is Http OPTIONS. 
I removed [Authenticate] from 
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
and changed
public class HelloService : Service
    {
        public object Options(Hello request) { return true; }
        [Authenticate]
        public object Get(Hello request)
        {
            return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
        }
    }